# How to take input as String given the String Length

Tags: java, string

How to take input from User as String given the String Length

The problem link:

http://www.practice.geeksforgeeks.org/problem-page.php?pid=295

MyApproach:

I used Scanner for the task to take the number of testcases and then took the String length as input:

But I am confused  how to take String of specified length.My search found that there is no method or constructor which can take string of specified length.

Can Anyone guide?

Below is my code:

```
 Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
 int T=sc.nextInt();
 for(int i=1;i<=T;i++)
  {
    int Strlength=sc.nextInt();
    String strnew=sc.next(); //How to take Stringofspecified character
    ..........
     .........
   }
```

Comment: you would want to read every char separately or read the whole line (`nextLine()`) and then just use the first n characters.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do that, you can simply force the user to reinsert the String if the length of the String does not match the given input.

```
 Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
 int T=sc.nextInt();
 for(int i=1;i<=T;i++)
  {
    int Strlength=sc.nextInt();
    String strnew = null;
    while (strnew == null || strnew.size() != Strlength) {
      strnew = sc.next(); 
    }
    ..........
     .........
   }
```

Comment: Zandanra Okay.Shouldn't the strnew.size()== Strlength) be equal?Then only we can take the input from user.

Comment: If you write strnew.size() == Strlength, you will execute the block of while each time the user insert a String of correct size. That is not what you want, you want to continue asking for user input until the input is correct. Once the user has inserted a String of length Strlength (strnew.size() == Strlength), the while loop will not execute anymore and you can perform your calculations

Answer (score 1):

A way to do this is inserting some kind of test, e.g.:

```
String strnew;
do{
   strnew=sc.next(); //How to take Stringofspecified character
}
while(strnew.length() != Strlength);
```

Comment: we could merge this answer with Simone Zandara's answer (since he was faster), since they mostly do the same. do-while just saves us the null-check.

Answer (score 1):

```
    String S = "";
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int D = sc.nextInt();
    for(int i=0;i<D;i++) {
         S = S + sc.next();
    }
    System.out.println(S);
```

Comment: makes string of specific length

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a way to do this.

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
int strLength = sc.nextInt();
sc.nextLine(); 
String strInput = sc.nextLine();
if(strInput.length()>strLength)
{
    str = str.substring(0, strlength);
}
// Now str length is equal to the desired string length
```